# How is it possible to web scrape a page using selenium on Render deployment environment?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, flask, deployment, selenium-chromedriver

I still cannot figure out how to webscrape a page on deployed environment on render, while locally works fine.

```
        `try:
            chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
            chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
            chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-dev-shm-usage")
            chrome_options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
            chrome_options.binary_location = os.environ.get("GOOGLE_CHROME_BIN")
            service = ChromeService(executable_path=os.environ.get("CHROMEDRIVER_PATH"))
            driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=chrome_options)
            # Navigate to the webpage
            driver.get(
                'https://www.vanguard.co.uk/professional/product/etf/equity/9679/ftse-all-world-ucits-etf-usd-accumulating')
            element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[@id='back-to-top']/europe-core-root/europe-core-product-page/aem-page/aem-model-provider/nds-aem-base-responsive-grid/div/nds-aem-base-responsive-grid/div[3]/europe-core-jump-links-list/div[4]/europe-core-gpx-product-detail-fund-cards-container/europe-core-product-detail-fund-cards/div/div[1]/europe-core-product-detail-fund-card/div[1]/div[2]")
            element_text = element.text
            price = element_text[3:]
            fund_price = session.query(MutualFund).filter_by(name=fund_name).first()
            fund_price.current_price = price
            print(price)
            driver.quit()
        except AttributeError:
            fund = session.query(MutualFund).filter_by(name=fund_name).first()
            price = fund.current_price
        session.commit()`
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.